# VBA List files in directory understanding

Tags: file, list, vba

The last two days i've been working with Excel VBA and it is going quite well. Currently I use the code below to list all file names in the specified directory. The code is working, but I also would like to understand why.

This is what I get from the code:

- The code looks in the directory for files with the extension .xlsx
  thence the *
- If the name is not empty, it iterates the i with + 1 and fills the
  array with the file name.
- Then, the file name become dir fName = Dir()

Can someone explain the reason for "fName = Dir()", what does the Dir() do?

My code:

```
fName = Dir("C:\xls\" & "*.xlsx")
While fName <> ""
    I = I + 1
    ReDim Preserve fileList(1 To I)
    fileList(I) = fName
     fName = Dir() 'uitzoeken hoet dit werkt
Wend
```

Thnx :)

Comment: possibly you find [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278779%28v=office.14%29.aspx) helpful...

Comment: Meehow, your comments are generally very long and productive so I believe your intentions are good.  However, your former site has been taken over by pharma scammers... readers beware clicking through on the above.  Please delete your comments and replace them with links from the Wayback machine to avoid spreading spam...

Answer (score 0):

```
 fName = Dir("C:\xls\" & "*.xlsx")
```

returns filename if it find a matching file otherwise return empty string

and to fetch next matching file call dir() function without any arguments

```
     fName = Dir() ' Get next entry.
```